# how to render special characters properly in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get characters like  â€™ â€¦ â€“ â€œ â€ â€˜ from DB. The table from which i am fetching is in latin1 character set. I need to show these characters properly. How to do this in Ruby on rails? Is there a function or piece of code which will replace these characters with correct ones?

Comment: Required reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the encoding of the DB string. Try the `encode` method of `String`:

```
dbstr.encode("iso-8859-1")
```

There are plenty of other encodings if ISO 8859 1 doesn't work for you. If the users browser doesn't support the right encoding, there are options you can pass to `encode` to get it to replace unknowns with `?`s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all encodings intil I found the right one

```
text.encode('windows-1250').force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode('utf-7').force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode('ibm852').force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode('shift_jis').force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode('iso-2022-jp').force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("Windows-1252").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("latin1").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-1").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-2").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-3").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-4").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-5").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-6").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-7").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-8").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-9").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-10").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-11").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-12").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-13").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-14").force_encoding("UTF-8")
text.encode("ISO-8859-15").force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

then I've created map of invalid characters and replaced them using script (inspired by https://markmcb.com/2011/11/07/replacing-with-utf-8-characters-in-ruby-on-rails/ )

```
def fix(text)
  replacements = [
    ['â€“',           "—"],
    ["â€”",           "–"],
    ["â€˜",           "‘"],
    ['â€¦',           '…'],
    ['â€™',           '’'],
    ['â€œ',           '“'],
    [/â€[[:cntrl:]]/, '”'],
    ['â€?',           '”'],
    ['â€ť',           '”'],
    ['â€ś',           '“'],
    ['â€¨',           '—'], # not sure about this one
    ['â€ł',           '″'],
    ['â€Ž',           ''], # emtpy str
    ['â€‚',           ''], # emtpy str
    ['â€‰',           ''], # emtpy str
    ['â€‹',           ''], # emtpy str
    ['â€',           ''], # emtpy str
    ["â€s'",           ''], # emtpy str
  ]

  new_text = text
  replacements.each { |set| new_text = new_text.gsub(set[0], set[1]) }
  new_text
end

# rails automatically will check if publication was changed and won't save if it wasn't changed
Publication.where('content like ?', "%â€%").find_each do |publication|
  publication.title         = fix(publication.title)
  publication.content       = fix(publication.content)
  publication.short_content = fix(publication.short_content)
  publication.save!
end
```

until `Publication.where('content like ?', "%â€%").count` was equal to 0